# Algorithm/ function to check the common part of more than 2 distributions

Tags: python, histogram, distribution, normal-distribution

**Problem:** To find a common part (more or less equally represented) of MORE than 2 distributions.

**Background and sample code:**

[image: Plot of 4 different distributions of some feature]

Imagine that we have four different distribution of the same feature. How to find their common part? It's clearly visible in the picture. Each distribution is printed with 25% of alpha transparency. The most "red" part is the common part of all four distributions. But how to find a two numbers that will describe this common part (~5.5-10 on the picture)?

Code [Python]:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu_1 = 5 #mean of the first distribution
mu_2 = 7 #mean of the second distribution
mu_3 = 9 #mean of the second distribution
mu_4 = 11 #mean of the second distribution

data_1 = np.random.normal(mu_1, 2.0, 1000)
data_2 = np.random.normal(mu_2, 2.0, 1000)
data_3 = np.random.normal(mu_3, 2.0, 1000)
data_4 = np.random.normal(mu_4, 2.0, 1000)

plt.hist(data_1,bins=50,alpha = 0.25, color= 'r')
plt.hist(data_2,bins=50,alpha = 0.25, color= 'r')
plt.hist(data_3,bins=50,alpha = 0.25, color= 'r')
plt.hist(data_4,bins=50,alpha = 0.25, color= 'r')
plt.show()
```

**Approaches and solutions:**

- Intersection: We can find intersections of two distributions and by that find the common part/ interval. We could use:

```
def return_intersection(hist_1, hist_2):
    minima = np.minimum(hist_1, hist_2)
    intersection = np.true_divide(np.sum(minima), np.sum(hist_2))
    return intersection
```

`hist_1 = np.histogram(data_1, bins=100, range=[-15, 15])    
hist_2 = np.histogram(data_2, bins=100, range=[-15, 15])    
int = return_intersection(hist_1, hist_2);`

This allows us to find the common part between TWO distributions. Another drawback is that it doesn't take into account the distances between bins. I would like to find strong results, not all the numbers that intersect, but **the part that is equal (more or less) in each set.**

**Question:** I'm sure that there is a function or algorithm that will help to reliable define this common part for multiple distrubutions/data sets, but I couldn't find one. It can be also written in MATLAB, if someone has any knowledge of that, please let me know.

Comment: Are you searching for the distance between the leftmost and the rightmost peaks? If you plot theoretical Gaussian CDFs, you'll get the (5, 11) range

Comment: Your “equal (more or less)” is inconsistent with your graphical description (which of course ignores excess height).

Comment: @ForceBru I'm looking for reliable way to obtain two values of the start and end of the intersection between more than two datasets (at least 4 datasets, which values can be plotted in a form of distribution plots). Did you use norm.cdf(x);?

Comment: @BloodyMary, I plotted cumulative normed CDF (like `hist(..., cumulative=True, normed=True)`) and shifted them down by `.5` because that's the middle on the Y axis. And hey, the leftmost and rightmost zeros turned out to be 5 and 11! This might be a feature of your data, though

Comment: @ForceBru I tried to do that, but cannot replicate your results :(. Could you elaborate on that and add this as a official answer, if you'e sure that it supposed to work for different types of data?